# MS SQL Server procedure from php fails with 500 when returning query is not empty

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure, which runs ok in Management Studio.

Then I have a php code, where I call it:

```
$sql = "EXEC MyProc @Param1=1, @Param2 = 2, @Param3 = '3'";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

if ($stmt === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    // and so on ...
}
```

it runs ok, with some set of parameters, that return 0 records (I simply get an empty array).

But when I change the params to return values, I get 500 error in JavaScript, which is calling the PHP script.

Here's how it's called in JS:

```
dojo.xhrPost({
    url: "/mySuperPhpCode.php",
    handleAs: "text",
    content: { Param1: 1, Param2: 2, Param3: 3 },
    load: function (response, ioArgs) {
        // some actions
    },
    error: function(response, ioArgs) {
        // some actions                            
    }
});
```

I know, that 500 error can point to many troubles, but I'm out of ideas for now.

My configuration: IIS 7.5, PHP 5.3.19. Ask, if any additional details needed.

**Upd 1:**
The code for processing results (inside while-loop):

```
$rez = array();
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    if (($key=="SomeDateFieldName1"||$key=="SomeDateFieldName2"||
         $key=="SomeDateFieldName3"||$key=="SomeDateFieldName4"||
         $key=="SomeDateFieldName5") && !is_null($value) ){
        $d=get_object_vars($value);
        $d=$d["date"];
        $zn=$d;
    } else {
        $zn=$value;
    }           

    $rez[$key] = $zn;           
}

$t[]=$rez ;
```

$t - will be returned from php-script.

One more addition: this php-file contains few calls to procedures (incoming parameters determines, which one will be called). Some of them work perfectly (in both cases: where no results and when there some records returned) and being processed with this code with no problems.

Comment: The 500 error isn't coming from SQL, or you'd see it when there were no results as well. I'm assuming, then, that the error is in how you handle the results when you get them. I'd revisit the contents of your loop on sqlsrv_fetch_array, because you might be handling the returned values incorrectly.

Comment: Hello, I wasn't thinking that it's SQL Server. Probably, I had to be more clear creating a title :) Anyways, I've updated the post with the code and some comments. Once more to clarify: I get this error only, when the procedure returns results. When it's empty, It goes with no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!
eemikula, you was right. The problem was in the result-processing section. I was trying to call **get_object_vars** on non-object value (in all previous cases, in the tables with the given "SomeDateFieldNameN" were DateTime objects, but in this table it was a varchar), so I added a check for it:

```
is_object($value)
```